# transpose pandas df column data to rows

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df as the following

```
email     | date | type
_________________________
xy@xy.com | 6/1  | order
xy@xy.com | 6/1  | return
cd@xy.com | 6/2  | return
ab@xy.com | 6/2  | return
```

I'm trying to individualize the type of column into each row keeping the data

```
email     | date | order | return
_________________________________
xy@xy.com | 6/1  | 1     |   0
xy@xy.com | 6/1  | 0     |   1
cd@xy.com | 6/2  | 0     |   0
ab@xy.com | 6/2  | 0     |   0
```

I've been trying to use `pd.melt` but the output doesn't seem to be what i'm looking for. referenced from [Pandas dataframe transpose with original row and column values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32213219/5656921)

Comment: In the column `return` is it okay that the third and fourth rows have a zero instead of a 1? Can you explain further what you're trying to achieve? get ones only when `email` is `xy@xy.com`? What you showed as your desired result doesn't really look like a transpose to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should have a look at how to create dummy variables from categorical columns.

There is a nice Pandas function to achieve that named "get_dummies":

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html

### Demonstration

```
df.drop('type', 1).join(pd.get_dummies(df['type']))

       email date  order  return
0  xy@xy.com  6/1      1       0
1  xy@xy.com  6/1      0       1
2  cd@xy.com  6/2      0       1
3  ab@xy.com  6/2      0       1
```

Comment: that's a great function - thanks for introducing this one to me!